# Smoothing out spikes in data

Tags: stochastic-processes, signal-processing, mathematical-modeling, time-series

I have a list of speed data for a driver (at infrequent intervals) that has certain spikes in it when the driver was too fast or suddenly braked. I'm looking for a formula that can smooth out the data so that my data is something similar to the chart below:

[image: Smoothed out chart data]

I've tried simple moving average and exponential moving average but is there any way of making the smoothed out data to stick/follow the trending data?

Might be worth mentioning that the data is real-time so the chart gets plotted on receiving each speed update.

Comment: Your graph is suggesting median filter... did you try a running median?

Comment: Yes there are whole fields in engineering which do this. Rather difficult to tell which approach would be good based on just one plot without any units or sampling information.

Comment: @N74 I'm not sure how to do this. When I searched, I mostly ran into pages related noise reduction in graphics

Comment: The median filter takes last $n$ samples from the acquisition vector and outputs the median of those samples. As you may know the median of a block of samples can be obtained sorting the block and taking the $(n-1)/2+1$ item from the ordered block (when $n$ is odd) or the mean of the items $n/2$ and $n/2+1$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: Thanks @N74 - As I'm a software developer, I'm not sure what to make of the answer below. Hence, I tried the median filter as you explained and achieved what I wanted.

Comment: Happy it helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us call the function $s(t)$. One approach we could do is to

1. Calculate local mean values $\mu(t)$ as 
   $$\mu(t) = (l*s)(t)$$
   Where $*$ is a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and $l$ is some function so that the convolution performs an estimate or approximation of local mean value: 
   $$(l*s)(t)\approx\frac{1}{2\alpha}\int_{t-\alpha}^{t+\alpha}s(x)dx$$
2. Now consider $|\mu(t)-s(t)|$ and calculate the maximum over each $[-\alpha,\alpha]$ interval.
3. Somehow sum up all of these maxima. This sum can be used as a measure to decide how much to smooth each point.

Which values of $\alpha$ we should use here will be dependent on the number of samples of each spike. We can also replace the maximum with a sort and locally distribute points over all the highest scorers.

This would become something of the opposite of a median filter in one sense. Instead of focusing on the median we focus on trying to quantify the outliers and how far out they lie.

Sorting can be a nasty operation but keep in mind that for this application we can use the redundancy of local neighbourhood overlaps to be able to do faster sorts.